# How to get the total count from a certain date from a dataframe having datatime column

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to pandas Dataframe. 
From MYSQL I have bound the following dataset to a Dataframe. Here how to get the total count for a particular date in jupyter. Also how to set a Datepicker widget in jupyter and by selecting the date range in the calendar how to show the total count for that selected date.

To be more specific:
1) Get total **count** for Todays date(by inputting only date) from RegistrationDate column
2) Get total **count** for Last 7 days(by inputting only date) from RegistrationDate column
3) Get total **count** by selecting the date range from Datepicker widget from RegistrationDate column

`No      RegistrationDate 
0   7       2019-07-23 12:23:25
1   9       2019-07-23 03:23:25
2   11      2019-07-23 08:10:10
3   13      2019-07-22 09:23:25
4   15      2019-07-22 04:01:02
5   17      2019-07-21 12:23:25
6   19      2019-07-20 12:23:25
7   21      2019-07-19 12:23:25
8   67      2019-06-04 12:23:25
9   68      2019-06-05 12:23:25
10  69      2019-06-06 12:23:25`

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far along with the specific issues/errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

## First index by date

Set index label to 'RegistrationDate' using

```
df.set_label('RegistrationDate', inplace=True)
```

## Objective 1

Get user input for date using

```
today = input('2019-07-22 04:01:02')

count1 = df.loc[today]
```

will return

```
15
```

## Objective 3

Ensure that your df.['RegistrationDate'] is a Series type

```
df.['RegistrationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.['RegistrationDate'])
```

get user inputs on start and end dates

```
start_date = input("start date:\t")
end_date = input("end date:\t")
```

create a Boolean mask and ensure that the input dates are datetime.datetime or datetime strings or pd.Timestamp

```
mask = (df['RegistrationDate'] > start_date) & (df['RegistrationDate'] <= end_date)
```

re-assign this to a temp_df and sum over columns

```
temp_df = df.loc[mask]
total_in_range = temp_df['No'].sum()
```